# Stop touch moves if counter reaches 3

Tags: objective-c, ios, drag-and-drop

I have an application with drag and drop a `UIView` feature. I should only let 3 drags and not more than that. How do I keep track of the number of drags? I tried incrementing a counter in `touchesBegan()`, but the counter got incremented on tapping the view also. I want it to be increased only when I drag the view. Also can you provide a snippet for dragging and dropping a small `UIView` into another view on the top. I don't know if I have used the right method.

My code:

```
(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    [self.view setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO]; 
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject]; 
    if ([touch view] == option1View || [touch view] == option2View ||
        [touch view] == option3View ||[touch view] == option4View) { 
            CGRect frame = [[touch view] frame];
            if(counter == 1){
                frame.origin.x = 10;
                frame.origin.y = 90; 
            }
            [[touch view] setFrame:frame];
```

I incremented my counter in touched began. I checked that if condition for 3 cases of counter

Comment: Um...decrement it in touches ended?

Comment: Hi,Welcome to SO. :) Could you please post some code here what you have written or at what point you failed to achieve it.

Comment: - (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    [self.view setMultipleTouchEnabled:NO];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
 if ([touch view] == option1View || [touch view] == option2View || [touch view] == option3View ||[touch view] == option4View) {
        CGRect frame = [[touch view] frame];
        if(counter == 1){
            frame.origin.x = 10;
            frame.origin.y = 90;  
        }
 [[touch view] setFrame:frame]; I incremented my counter in touched began. I checked that if condition for 3 cases of counter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has a *gesture recognizer* exactly for dragging. It is `UIPangestureRecognizer`. It recognizes just pan gestures and not tap or something else.

Here is doc http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

You can manage your pan/drag gestures easier then using `touchesBegan()` etc...

From Doc:
`UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` ends when all fingers are lifted.

You can check the state and increment your counter.

Comment: Can u help me with the code pls.. Im new to xcode. I have 4 small views in the bottom and want the view i touch and drag to move to the top view.

Comment: Here is a sample code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672677/how-to-use-uipangesturerecognizer-to-move-object-iphone-ipad
It is old, but should give you the idea

Comment: And another sample code from apple http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleGestureRecognizers/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009460