# UipanGesture is not working on Uiswitch

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiswitch, uipangesturerecognizer

I have added a uiswitch and want to move it to another position via gesture. but uipangesture is not working on uiswitch.. below is my code

```
    UISwitch *swich = [[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 40, 50)];

    swich.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                       initWithTarget:self 
                                       action:@selector(switchdraged:)];
    [swich addGestureRecognizer:gesture];

    [self.view addSubview:swich];
```

function switchdraged is not being called..

below is switchdraged function

```
- (void)switchdraged:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) gesture1
{
        UISwitch *swich = (UISwitch *)gesture1.view;
        CGPoint translation = [gesture1 translationInView:swich];
        swich.center = CGPointMake(swich.center.x + translation.x, 
                                swich.center.y + translation.y);
        // reset translation
        [gesture1 setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:swich];
}
```

Comment: can we see the definition of labelDragged:  ?

Comment: i have added the definition please check

Comment: I personally never had to use this.. but you can look here.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6687064/919545 hoping this helps

Answer (score 1):

I think `UIPanGestureRecognizer` will not  work with `UISwitch`.

The class reference says

> UIPanGestureRecognizer is a concrete subclass of UIGestureRecognizer
>   that looks for panning (dragging) gestures. The user must be pressing
>   one or more fingers on a view while they pan it.

*SO UISwitch is  probably overridden for changing the state*

I have created a sample application

The same code working well  with `UILabel` instead of `UISwitch`. I have discussed with Abizern. He told me that **It's probably overridden for changing the state**.

Please describe well what you need to do with UISwitch.

This way may help you

**1.Create a switch inside a view and add as a subview**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{  

    UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100)];  
    containerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                       initWithTarget:self 
                                       action:@selector(switchdraged:)];
    [containerView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];


    UISwitch *swich = [[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 40, 50)];    
    swich.userInteractionEnabled = YES;



    [containerView addSubview:swich];    

    [self.view addSubview:containerView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:containerView];


    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (void)switchdraged:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) gesture1
{
    NSLog(@"triggered");

    UIView *swich = (UIView *)gesture1.view;
    CGPoint translation = [gesture1 translationInView:swich];
    swich.center = CGPointMake(swich.center.x + translation.x, 
                               swich.center.y + translation.y);
    // reset translation
    [gesture1 setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:swich];
}
```

or

This link may help you

[Draggable Buttons and Labels](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/11/draggable-buttons-labels/)

Comment: if that is the case than putting the switch in a UIView and than adding the UIPanGesture to it should work..

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava: i have added that too.. :)

Comment: hi ramshad could you please solve my this problem? i will be highly obliged     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975022/uilongpressgesturerecognizer-issue-with-uibutton-and-uilabel

Comment: yeah.. i am going to post answer.. before that, if my solution works, u can accept my answer through ticking the tick symbol(which displays top left of my answer or below the up-vote)