# UILongPressGestureRecognizer issue with uibutton and uilabel

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, gesture

i have 2 uibutton and 1 label and longpressgesture is bounded to these control. when longpress is taken place on any control then how to get the object on which longpress is taken place below is the code that i have written.

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(wasDragged:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
//[self.view addSubview:btn];
btn.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

// add it
[self.view addSubview:btn];
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                           initWithTarget:self 
                                           action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;
[btn addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

below is function that is called on longpress

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(id)sender{
 }
```

if i printing description of sender then i get

```
 <UILongPressGestureRecognizer: 0x6aa4480; state = Began; view = <UIRoundedRectButton 0x6aa9570>; target= <(action=handleLongPress:, target=<ViewController 0x6a8cc60>)>>
```

from it how can i get the refrence of object on whcih longpress event takes place
i mean how do i know whether i preessed UiLabel or Uibutton?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the UIGestureRecognizer's (the parent class) view property:

> @property(nonatomic, readonly) UIView *view
>
> The view the gesture recognizer is attached to. (read-only)
>
> @property(nonatomic, readonly) UIView *view
> Discussion
> You attach (or add) a gesture recognizer to a UIView object using the addGestureRecognizer: method.

Comment: if it is then sender dont have view property i have checked it already

Comment: what is the class of the sender? if it's UILongPressGestureRecognizer, it should have a view property, since it's a child class of UIGestureRecognizer.

Comment: never mind i have solved it in this way  UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gest = (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender;
    UIView *v  =  gest.view;

Comment: The sender is the UILongPressGestureRecognizer, the property is inherited from UIGestureRecognizer. That is how you assigned the selector when initializing your UILongPressGestureRecognizer. What you did with the casting was just to get the compiler to ignore the warning. You can also declare the method to receive an UIGestureRecognizer object, hence avoiding the warning. So, my original answer is correct.

Comment: sory i dint get it could you please give an example if possible?

Comment: you most likely declared your method like this: - (void) handleLongPress:(id)sender; change it to - (void) handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer; There, you can just access the view property without using casting.

Comment: yea i did it too but i forgot what problem i faced from it... anyways thanks a lot.. one thing more could you please tell how can in directly talk to you from ur profile becoze here i am getting warning of long chat on comment not possible. i dnt know much about this site how to reach peoples

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender{


    if ([sender.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {

            UIButton *myButton = (UIButton *)sender.view; // here is your sender object or Tapped button

            if (myButton.tag == 1) {

                    //sender is first Button. Because we assigned 1 as Button1 Tag when created.
            }
            else if (myButton.tag == 2){

                    //sender is second Button. Because we assigned 2 as Button2 Tag when created.
            }
    }

    if ([sender.view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {

        UILabel *myLabel = (UILabel *)sender.view; // here is your sender object or Tapped label.

    }


}
```