# Can I change the subview order during a UIGesture sequence like UIPanGesture -iOS

Tags: objective-c

This code loops through adding a subview to the current subview (it is a card game)...

```
        //Creates the Card's view and adds it to the cardContainerView
        CardView *cardView = [[CardView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 67,99)];
        [cardContainerView addSubview:cardView];


        //Assign the UIGesture to the CardView

        //For panning and dragging
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
        [cardView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
```

...once the deal is done, I want to pick a card with a touch gesture and drag it - during this sequence I want that card to be hovering over all other cards (like in solitaire where you want to add a card from one column to another)

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672677/how-to-use-uipangesturerecognizer-to-move-object-iphone-ipad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need to do is something like this:

in handlePanGesture:

```
- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    UIView *touchedView = recognizer.view;
    [touchedView.superview bringSubviewToFront:touchedView];
    ... // Rest of your code here.
}
```

If `touchedView.superview` doesn't work, you might want to consider making cardContainerView a property of your class and access it as such in your `handlePanGesture:` method.