# "pull up" animation on drag

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I am trying to achieve an effect where a user drags on a tab and it reveals a toolbar underneath what you dragged. It is similar to the pandora app linked. On the Pandora app, next to the thumbs up, there is a tab. When you drag it up, it shows a volume bar underneath. I tried detecting gestures on the "tab" to animate it moving upwards, but failed miserably. Is there a better way of achieving the drag-to-reveal effect?

[image: http://www.theiospost.com/storage/Pandora-4.0-iPhone5-2.png?__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1351551597464]

Answer (score 2):

There's no better way to create a "drag-to-reveal" effect; `UIPanGestureRecognizer` is your best option.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6687064/953105) for guidance on moving `UIView`s with a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.