# AVPlayer freezing when pan gesture is made

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm developing an music app written in swift 2.0. 
Right now, I'm implementing video player part with AVPlayer.

I wanted to add a feature that if user **swipes down any place in the modal(in the movie player), the modal gets dismissed downward.** (like as ios youtube player; they don't actually dissmiss the player though)

I researched how to implement this feature and found the solution below

Stackoverflow answer : [In iOS, how to drag down to dismiss a modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290313/in-ios-how-to-drag-down-to-dismiss-a-modal) 
 
Full Tutorial : http://www.thorntech.com/2016/02/ios-tutorial-close-modal-dragging/

It works well but there is a problem that
**AVPlayer is freezing when the pan gesture is made** (while holding a finger on the screen). The Audio is playing normally. Only the video is freezing.

Here is the code handling pan gestures.

```
@IBAction func handleGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let percentThreshold:CGFloat = 0.2

        // convert y-position to downward pull progress (percentage)
        let translation = sender.translationInView(view)
        let verticalMovement = translation.y / view.bounds.height
        let downwardMovement = fmaxf(Float(verticalMovement), 0.0)
        let downwardMovementPercent = fminf(downwardMovement, 1.0)
        let progress = CGFloat(downwardMovementPercent)

        guard let interactor = interactor else { return }

        switch sender.state {
        case .Began:
            interactor.hasStarted = true
            dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        case .Changed:
            interactor.shouldFinish = progress > percentThreshold
            interactor.updateInteractiveTransition(progress)
        case .Cancelled:
            interactor.hasStarted = false
            interactor.cancelInteractiveTransition()
        case .Ended:
            interactor.hasStarted = false
            if interactor.shouldFinish {
                interactor.finishInteractiveTransition()
            } else {
                interactor.cancelInteractiveTransition()
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

**After "dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)" is called (case .Began:), *"currentVideoFrameRate" (avPlayer.currentItem?.tracks.first?.currentVideoFrameRate) is reduced from approx. 29 to 4***.

It seems the rate controlled internally. I still don't know how to prevent from lowering the frame rate.
I want to make AVPlayer play video normally even if it is on transitioning (.Changed status)
Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey kyle, have you had any luck with this problem? I'm having the same issue, can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Nope.. I still have the issue. Temporarily I removed an animation effect for transitioning. let me know if you find a solution!

Comment: Did you solve this maybe?

Answer (score 0):

In swift 5.0
in AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate Method:

```
func playerViewController(_ playerViewController: AVPlayerViewController, willEndFullScreenPresentationWithAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator){
        playerViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Will solve the issue.