# Slide down to dismiss presented navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I want to implement slide down interaction and dismiss view controller, for which i referred [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290313/in-ios-how-to-drag-down-to-dismiss-a-modal/35205596) , but this works only for dismissing a single view controller presented from view controller.

In my case, i have presented a navigation controller as user can push to another view from that view controller, but drag down to dismiss doesn't work with navigation controller.

UPDATED:It should work as - slide down gesture is triggered from any of the screens, (for eg: from main screen or pushed screen/detail screen) the navigation controller should dismiss completely.

Please suggest if anyone has come across implementing the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show what you are doing in order for someone to figure out what's missing. Please share your code

Comment: I have used the same code from the link which i have linked in the question,created ViewControllerPannable class, and used it, but it doesnt seems to work.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that a modal controller and a navigation controller have different ways of `dismissing` a controller. For a modal controller, you would use `dismissViewController` whereas in a navigation controller, you would use `navigationController.popViewController` (because it is pushed onto a navigation stack)

Comment: i have to implement as - on swipe down or panning down the view controller it should dismiss whole navigation controller.

Answer (score -1):

You can add PanGesture in your navigation controller. Using `- (CGPoint)velocityInView:(UIView *)view` you will know in which direct user panned. if view was panned down manage its constraint accordingly and if it is more than a threshold value pop that view.

Comment: @Malik but it works with modal presentation. Which is the problem. It is not too complex to implement so just gave an option to implement according to the requirement.

Comment: A gesture recogniser is not bound by the presentation style of a view controller. Using a navigation controller in lieu of a modal controller does not render a gesture recogniser useless.