# iOS modal interactive dismissal freezes

Tags: ios, swift, transition

I have created a UIPercentDriven Transition which modally presents a popover view containing a tableView. Then, following stack exchange posts such as this one: [In iOS, how to drag down to dismiss a modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290313/in-ios-how-to-drag-down-to-dismiss-a-modal), I added a panGestureRecognizer to control the dismissal of the modal view. Then, I attempted to add functionality so that the user can continue to swipe downward once the tableview has reached the top to trigger the percent driven transition.

Here is a link to the project on github:https://github.com/KaplanAlex/modalViewDismissal

This transition was based on moving the frame of the modal view off of the screen. I also created the transition by using snapshots (which is commented out in the github project) and have the same issues. For some reason, the interactive dismissal works well unless the user moves the modal view back up after starting the dismissal and then continues to swipe upward after the modal view has reached the top of the view, the entire application seems to freeze. It doesnt crash, but also doesnt respond to taps anywhere on the screen. Even cancel button cannot be pressed. Has anyone encountered this issue before? Thanks for the help.