# How to drag down to dismiss a modal with ObjectC

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to dismiss a modal view with dragging down photo like twitter app's photo views.

I found [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290313/in-ios-how-to-drag-down-to-dismiss-a-modal/), but it written in Swift.

I need Object-C version.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use UISwipeGestureRecognizer (Down) to achieve the behaviour.

Add gesture to the model view using below code:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *downGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer   alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(downGestureHandler:)];
[gestureRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer: downGestureRecognizer];
```

The method to dismiss the model view:

```
-(void) downGestureHandler:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

        //Code to dismiss model view with animation
}
```