# Using pan down to dismiss a UINavigationController resizes the UINavigationBar with respect to the top safe area

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uipangesturerecognizer

I am using a pan gesture recognizer to dismiss a UINavigationController. I'm using the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47339617/6872794), with modifications to fit my NavigationController and I am also adding the gesture recognizer to the actual VC inside the container view.

Everything works fine except the fact that when I swipe down, the navigation bar changes its position whenever the y value is > 0.0.

What I think is happening is that the navigation bar is attached to the top safe area, and when it leaves that top safe area, it automatically resizes itself to the top of the view.

How could I simply implement it so that the size of the navigation bar either extends underneath the safe area at the top or completely disregards it, and instead constraints to the view that it's in?

Here are the pictures:

Normal:
[image: Normal]

Swiping down to dismiss:
[image: Swipe Down]

Here is the code I am using for my UINavigationController

```
//
//  PannableViewController.swift
//

import UIKit

class PannableViewController: UINavigationController {
    public var minimumVelocityToHide = 1500 as CGFloat
    public var minimumScreenRatioToHide = 0.5 as CGFloat
    public var animationDuration = 0.2 as TimeInterval

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Listen for pan gesture
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onPan(_:)))

        if let lastVC = self.childViewControllers.last {
            lastVC.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
        }

    }

    func slideViewVerticallyTo(_ y: CGFloat) {
        self.view.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: y)
    }

    @objc func onPan(_ panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        switch panGesture.state {
        case .began, .changed:
            // If pan started or is ongoing then
            // slide the view to follow the finger
            let translation = panGesture.translation(in: view)
            let y = max(0, translation.y)
            self.slideViewVerticallyTo(y)
            break
        case .ended:
            // If pan ended, decide it we should close or reset the view
            // based on the final position and the speed of the gesture
            let translation = panGesture.translation(in: view)
            let velocity = panGesture.velocity(in: view)
            let closing = (translation.y > self.view.frame.size.height * minimumScreenRatioToHide) ||
                (velocity.y > minimumVelocityToHide)

            if closing {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, animations: {
                    // If closing, animate to the bottom of the view
                    self.slideViewVerticallyTo(self.view.frame.size.height)
                }, completion: { (isCompleted) in
                    if isCompleted {
                        // Dismiss the view when it dissapeared
                        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
                    }
                })
            } else {
                // If not closing, reset the view to the top
                UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, animations: {
                    self.slideViewVerticallyTo(0)
                })
            }
            break
        default:
            // If gesture state is undefined, reset the view to the top
            UIView.animate(withDuration: animationDuration, animations: {
                self.slideViewVerticallyTo(0)
            })
            break
        }
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?)   {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen;
        self.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical;
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen;
        self.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you able to share sample project?

Comment: @kthorat Yes, here you go https://github.com/returnzer0/SampleNavBar

Comment: Thank you. I need to leave now. It is interesting problem, will look into this after coming back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is something I put together quickly, please make optimisations and improvements as you need.

I have updated your code to use transition delegate. Read up on UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate & UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning to get better understanding of how [View Controller Transitions](http://raywenderlich.com/170144/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions-getting-started) works.

Following is updated PannableViewController. What is Changed?

-Added transition delegate, it gives you better control on transition between VCs

-updated pan gesture handler

-Changed minimumScreenRatioToHid (it was too high, keep 0.5 if you want)

```
class PannableViewController: UINavigationController {
    public var minimumVelocityToHide = 1500 as CGFloat
    public var minimumScreenRatioToHide = 0.3 as CGFloat
    public var animationDuration = 0.2 as TimeInterval

    private lazy var transitionDelegate: TransitionDelegate = TransitionDelegate()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.transitioningDelegate = self.transitionDelegate

        // Listen for pan gesture
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onPan(_:)))

        if let lastVC = self.childViewControllers.last {
            lastVC.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
        }
    }

    @objc func onPan(_ panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let translation = panGesture.translation(in: self.view)
        let verticalMovement = translation.y / self.view.bounds.height
        let downwardMovement = fmaxf(Float(verticalMovement), 0.0)

        let downwardMovementPercent = fminf(downwardMovement, 1.0)
        let progress = CGFloat(downwardMovementPercent)

        let velocity = panGesture.velocity(in: self.view)
        let shouldFinish = progress > self.minimumScreenRatioToHide || velocity.y > self.minimumVelocityToHide

        switch panGesture.state {
        case .began:
            self.transitionDelegate.interactiveTransition.hasStarted = true
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        case .changed:
            self.transitionDelegate.interactiveTransition.shouldFinish = shouldFinish
            self.transitionDelegate.interactiveTransition.update(progress)
        case .cancelled:
            self.transitionDelegate.interactiveTransition.hasStarted = false
            self.transitionDelegate.interactiveTransition.cancel()
        case .ended:
            self.transitionDelegate.interactiveTransition.hasStarted = false
            self.transitionDelegate.interactiveTransition.shouldFinish ? self.transitionDelegate.interactiveTransition.finish() : self.transitionDelegate.interactiveTransition.cancel()
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?)   {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen;
        self.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical;
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen;
        self.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical;
    }
}
```

Following is UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate and couple of model classes.

```
class InteractiveTransition: UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition {
        public var hasStarted: Bool = false
        public var shouldFinish: Bool = false
    }

class Transition {
    public var isPresenting: Bool = false
    public var presentDuration: TimeInterval = 0.5
    public var dismissDuration: TimeInterval = 0.5
}

class TransitionDelegate: NSObject, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    lazy var transition: Transition = Transition()
    lazy var interactiveTransition: InteractiveTransition = InteractiveTransition()

    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController,
                             presenting: UIViewController,
                             source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {

        self.transition.isPresenting = true
        return self
    }

    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        self.transition.isPresenting = false
        return self
    }

    func interactionControllerForDismissal(using animator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
        return self.interactiveTransition.hasStarted ? self.interactiveTransition : nil
    }
}


extension TransitionDelegate:  UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return self.transition.isPresenting ? self.transition.presentDuration : self.transition.dismissDuration
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        guard let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from),
            let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to) else {
                transitionContext.completeTransition(false)
                return
        }

        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
        containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

        if self.transition.isPresenting {

            let finalFrameForVC = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: toVC)
            toVC.view.frame = finalFrameForVC.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
            containerView.addSubview(toVC.view)

            // Additional ways to animate, Spring velocity & damping
            UIView.animate(withDuration: self.transition.presentDuration,
                           delay: 0.0,
                           options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                           animations: {
                            toVC.view.frame = finalFrameForVC
            }, completion: { _ in
                transitionContext.completeTransition(true)
            })

        } else {

            var finalFrame = fromVC.view.frame
            finalFrame.origin.y += finalFrame.height

            // Additional ways to animate, Spring velocity & damping
            UIView.animate(withDuration: self.transition.dismissDuration,
                           delay: 0.0,
                           options: .curveEaseOut,
                           animations: {
                            fromVC.view.frame = finalFrame
                            toVC.view.alpha = 1.0
            },
                           completion: { _ in
                            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

[image: enter image some cool description here]