# Panning UIViewController makes things pinned to safe area jump to the superview

Tags: ios, swiftui, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I'm using this code to make a UIViewController pannable take from this so [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41077052/3075340).

```
class ViewControllerPannable: UIViewController {
  var panGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer?
  var originalPosition: CGPoint?
  var currentPositionTouched: CGPoint?
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGestureAction(_:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer!)
  }
  
  func panGestureAction(_ panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = panGesture.translation(in: view)
    
    if panGesture.state == .began {
      originalPosition = view.center
      currentPositionTouched = panGesture.location(in: view)
    } else if panGesture.state == .changed {
        view.frame.origin = CGPoint(
          x: translation.x,
          y: translation.y
        )
    } else if panGesture.state == .ended {
      let velocity = panGesture.velocity(in: view)

      if velocity.y >= 1500 {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2
          , animations: {
            self.view.frame.origin = CGPoint(
              x: self.view.frame.origin.x,
              y: self.view.frame.size.height
            )
          }, completion: { (isCompleted) in
            if isCompleted {
              self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
        })
      } else {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
          self.view.center = self.originalPosition!
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works great on older phones that don't have a notch. But if the phone has a notch, once you start panning, any views pinned to the safe area jump to the superview. I think the issue is in the

```
view.frame.origin = CGPoint(
              x: translation.x,
              y: translation.y
            )
```

But I'm not sure how to make anything that was pinned to the safe area stay that way when panning.

Answer (score 0):

You want to avoid `layoutSubviews` after you drag the view outside the `superview`'s `frame`.  As long as you are not calling `setNeedsLayout` manually, you can achieve this by ensuring that last `frame.size` change happens *before* crossing outside. Just make enough variables to precisely control for this situation.

I encountered this issue with a custom action-sheet-like presentation. When I pulled the view down to dismiss, there was no problem. But when I pulled the view up to stretch and *then* down, the `safeAreaInsets` jumped from 0 to non-zero suddenly.

The reason was because my view stretched upwards but not downwards. Pull up was `frame.origin.y` change and a `frame.size.height` change. Downwards was only a `frame.origin.y` change. However, `UIPanGestureRecognizer` does not have infinite granularity, and so the jump from negative to positive `translation` caused `origin.y` to change *at the same time* as `frame.size.height` in the downward direction. This triggered `layoutSubviews` while the view was partially outside the `superview`, which meant it ran layout code that suddenly acknowledged a `safeAreaInsets` change.

My solution is essentially:

```
if translation < 0 && oldTranslation > 0 || translation > 0 && oldTranslation < 0 {
   view.frame = originalFrame
} else {
   view.frame = calculate(translation)
}
```

This forces the view to be a static size before it crosses the `superview`'s boundary, ensuring that `layoutSubviews` is called with the correct `safeAreaInsets`, but as the position changes, the `safeArea` does not.

Your situation may be a little different if you have something else triggering `layoutSubviews`. You might have to hunt that down.

Another thing I notice is that you're moving the `UIViewController`'s `view` when it might have a `parent`, which could have other implications or edge cases because `safeArea` is inherited from the `UIViewController` hierarchy rather than solely `superview`.