# How to disable second touch in an SpriteKit game?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

The player drags a sprite in my game but when accidentally touch the screen with a second finger it screws the movement obviously.

I used the following solutions for disable the second touch, but unfortunately it doesn't work:

```
//--------------

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*) touches withEvent:(UIEvent*) event {    

    if (touches.count == 1 && draggedNode == nil) {

        CGPoint pos = [[touches anyObject] locationInNode:self];
        SKNode * touchedNode = [self nodeAtPoint:pos];

        if([touchedNode.name isEqual: @"shooterBall"]){
            draggedNode = touchedNode;
        }
        draggedNodeOffset = CGPointMake(draggedNode.position.x - pos.x, draggedNode.position.y - pos.y);
    }   

}

//--------------

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*) touches withEvent:(UIEvent*) event {    
    if (touches.count <= 1) {    
        CGPoint pos = [[touches anyObject] locationInNode:self];
        draggedNode.position = CGPointMake(pos.x + draggedNodeOffset.x, pos.y+draggedNodeOffset.y);
    }
}

//--------------

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*) touches withEvent:(UIEvent*) event {   
    draggedNode = nil;   
}

//--------------
```

Do you have any solution for this?

Thanks your help in advance!

Comment: why don't you use a gesture recognizer. It will allow you to specify how many touches can occur at once

Comment: I thought that it is used for swipes and pinch.

Comment: yeah, you want the player to swipe or pan his finger over the screen, right?

Comment: Yes, but not just one swipe, he can drag the sprite to any place of the screen. Is it the same as pan gesture?

Comment: Yeah. Here, I'll give a more detailed explanation

Comment: I started with this now:
https://spritekitlessons.wordpress.com/2013/10/03/gesture-recognizers-with-sprite-kit/

...but in my skscene I already have another delegate for the physics collision detection -  SKPhysicsContactDelegate...

How you use two delegates in one header?

Comment: You can use touchesBegan/touchesMoved to track a single touch

Comment: This is what i do, but still if I use the first touch only, it doesn't work eaither.
firstTouch = (UITouch *)[[[event allTouches] allObjects] objectAtIndex: 0];

Comment: iOS automatically tracks all touch events, so it's easy to determine if a different finger touches the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to implement `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in your scene. It will allow you to track the location of the user's touch and at the same time control other "stray" touches: [UIPanGestureRecognizer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPanGestureRecognizer/translationInView:)

After you initialize it, you need to implement a method to handle the user's pans. You will have to set flags inside of this method to control when the swipe started/ended. I think [this answer on StackOverflow gave a really good explanation of using it (with Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672677/how-to-use-uipangesturerecognizer-to-move-object-iphone-ipad). BTW, when you initialize it, you should set the gesture recognizer's property `maximumNumberOfTouches` to 1 (that will cause it to ignore other touches while the user is panning).

The trickier part will be to translate the same code you wrote before to gesture recognizer. The difference is that your handler will be called only once for each "swipe" or "pan", while the touches method you are using now is called each time there is a "touch". There are a few ways to proceed at this point, and you could try whatever you like, but I think that this would be the easiest way to go once you have your gesture recognizer set up (spoiler):

1. make sure the gesture recognizer is an instance variable so you can access it from all methods.
2. go to the `update:` method and make an if statement that checks if `gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`
3. use the same algorithm that you had before in this if statement. To check the location that the touch is at use the method: `locationInView:`. Use `self.view` as the parameter.

Hope this helped! good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My only problem is I already use a delegate for the skscene for the physics collision detection. How can I have the other one for the gestures?

Comment: No problem, the physics "delegation" will have nothing to do with the gesture handling, actually. Physics stuff will be called in `didBeginContact:`, while gesture stuff will be called in another method that you define yourself (the action:@selector(insertyourmethodnamehere)) when you initialize it. Just check out that second link I gave you. It will help a lot.

Comment: If I have the <SKPhysicsContactDelegate> I cannot put the <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> in the skscene header. It only accepts one delegate, that's my problem.

Comment: Ohh, noo you don't need to do any of that. Its much easier to just initialize with the action selector like in that link I put in. Basically you configure the gesture recognizer to call a method inside of your scene and pass itself in as an argument.