# How to close UITableViewController by dragging down(panning)

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm working on making an iOS app.

Now I'm stuck to do the following stuff.

- detail screen is popped up as modal screen
- user wants to close the modal window by dragging down like Twitter's photo screen

And I tried to code by reference to [How to use UIPanGestureRecognizer to move object? iPhone/iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672677/how-to-use-uipangesturerecognizer-to-move-object-iphone-ipad)

My code looks like below.
It makes tableView move to strange direction and then close the modal.

```
var firstX: CGFloat = 0
var firstY: CGFloat = 0
var finalX: CGFloat = 0
var finalY: CGFloat = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let recognizer : UIPanGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "move:")
    recognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1
    recognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1
    self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
}

func move(sender : UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    print("move")

    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(tableView)
    var translatedPoint : CGPoint = sender.translationInView(self.view)
    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
        firstX = 0 // (sender.view?.center.x)!
        firstY = (tableView?.center.y)!
    }
    translatedPoint = CGPointMake(firstX+translatedPoint.x, firstY)
    tableView?.center = translatedPoint

    if sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
        let velocityY = 0.2 * sender.velocityInView(self.view).y
        finalX = firstX //translatedPoint.x + velocityX
        finalY = translatedPoint.y + velocityY

        if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation)) {

            if finalY < 0 {
                finalY = 0
            } else if finalY > 1024 {
                finalY = 1024
            }

        } else {

            if finalY < 0 {
                finalY = 0
            } else if finalY > 768 {
                finalY = 1024
            }
        }

        let animationDuration = ( abs(velocityY) * 0.0002 ) + 0.2

        UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
        UIView.setAnimationDuration(Double(animationDuration))
        UIView.setAnimationCurve(UIViewAnimationCurve.EaseOut)
        UIView.setAnimationDelegate(self)
        UIView.setAnimationDidStopSelector("animationDidFinish")
        self.view.center = CGPointMake(finalX, finalY)
        UIView.commitAnimations()


    }
}

func animationDidFinish() {
    print("animationDidFinish")
    if finalY > 50 {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Does anyone point me to the right direction?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a custom modal animation.  You should read [Customizing the Transition Animations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CustomizingtheTransitionAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH16-SW1) from the [Presentation and Transitions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/PresentingaViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH14-SW1) section of the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS).

Specifically there is a part in there on [Adding Interactivity to Your Transitions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CustomizingtheTransitionAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH16-SW5), but you will probably need to read more than just that part to understand.

In short, you will have to create an implementation of [`UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate/interactionControllerForPresentation:) and assign that to the transitioning delegate of the view controller being presented.  The job of the [`UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate/interactionControllerForPresentation:) is to vend a number of other objects to `UIKit` that handle a custom animation (and optionally presentation) for presenting and dismissing the view controller.

In addition to your implementation of [`UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate/interactionControllerForPresentation:) you will also have to create implementations of [`UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) and [`UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning).  These objects will ultimately be the ones performing the relevant animations, and they are the objects vended to `UIKit` by your [`UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate/interactionControllerForPresentation:) implementation.

Comment: I don't have any that I could post.  Almost certainly though there are examples of using these APIs available in the documentation and/or from WWDC sessions.