# SceneKit - Ignore touches on an SCNNode in the foreground and transfer touch to a background node

Tags: swift, swiftui, scenekit, arkit, arscnview

I am trying to make an app where users can measure distances on an ARSCNView. I have a scenario where there are 2 SCNNodes on top of each other. Node1 is always at the front because of its depth information. Node2 however is useful for measuring and getting accurate measurements. I would like to ignore touches on node1 and only get the location of touch on node2.

When I hide node1, the touches are properly recognized on node2. However, I still need node1 to be visible to the user.

I tried to change the renderingOrder and making sure that node2 is added to the rootNode after node1 is, but was of no success.

I also verified the hitTest array on tapping on a point, only the one hitTest on node1 is recognized and present in the array. So I'm not able to select a different hitTestResult either.

Further info: Node1 is a huge node which occupies a large space and node2 is formed from multiple child nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably do this using different Bitmasks (the `categoryBitmask` of the `SCNNode`) on which perform the `hitTestResult`.

Or if you have `physicsBodies` involved on the `SCNNodes`, you can do a rayTest to its physics `categoryBitmasks`. (`scene.physicsWorld.rayTestWithSegment`)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @ZAY for your answer. It worked perfectly.

I got further help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53490388/arkit-hittest-options-to-select-placed-3d-objects-not-working) answer.

What I did:

```
struct NodeType: OptionSet {
  let rawValue: Int

  static let `default` = NodeType(rawValue: 1)
  static let userInteraction = NodeType(rawValue: 4)
}
```

My foreground node has a default category bitmask of 1. I did not specify anything.

To my background node, I assigned bitmask as:

```
node.categoryBitMask = NodeType.userInteraction.rawValue
```

When performing hitTest, I provided this bitMask as an option:

```
let touchPosition = gesture.location(in: arSceneView)
let hitResults = arSceneView.hitTest(touchPosition, options: [SCNHitTestOption.categoryBitMask: NodeType.userInteraction.rawValue])
```

Voila, my foreground node is ignored and the background node gets the hitTest interaction.