# Swift: Obtain and save the updated SCNNode over time using projectPoint in scenekit

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

I am trying to use `projectPoint` to get the 2D information of the updated SCNNode in scenekit and save them.

Based on ignotusverum's suggestion, I am able to save the SCNNode in to a path in a button.

```
     var lastPosition: CGPoint?
     func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
            guard anchor == currentFaceAnchor,
                let contentNode = selectedContentController.contentNode,
                contentNode.parent == node
                else { return }
            for (index, vertex) in vertices.enumerated() {
            let vertex = sceneView.projectPoint(node.convertPosition(SCNVector3(vertex), to: nil))
            let xVertex = CGFloat(vertex.x)
            let yVertex = CGFloat(vertex.y)
            Position = CGPoint(x: xVertex, y: yVertex)
           }
            selectedContentController.session = sceneView?.session
            selectedContentController.sceneView = sceneView
            selectedContentController.renderer(renderer, didUpdate: contentNode, for: anchor)
        }
```

---

Started saving via a start button:

```
    private var fpsTimer = Timer()
    private var currentCaptureFrame = 0
    @IBAction private func startPressed() {
        currentCaptureFrame = 0 //inital capture frame
        fpsTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1/fps, repeats: true, block: {(timer) -> Void in self.recordData()})
    }
```

---

Saved them via a stop button clicks:

```
@IBAction private func stopPressed() {
    do {
        fpsTimer.invalidate() //turn off the timer
        let capturedData = captureData.map{$0.stringRepresentation}.joined(separator:"\(lastPosition)>")
        let dir: URL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last! as URL
        let url = dir.appendingPathComponent("testing.txt")
        try capturedData.appendLineToURL(fileURL: url as URL)
    }
    catch {
        print("Could not write to file")
    }
}
```

So far works fine with the points being saved. The problem is that in the saved data, I realized the data is only saving one frame of the x and y vertices. For example:

```
[(411.0618591308594, 534.4215087890625), (410.7286071777344, 544.9381713867188), (411.5425720214844, 522.1063232421875), (412.0340881347656, 512.1854248046875),... 

[(411.0618591308594, 534.4215087890625), (410.7286071777344, 544.9381713867188), (411.5425720214844, 522.1063232421875), (412.0340881347656, 512.1854248046875)
```

The data is repeating with one frame rather than the period I want to save from the moment when I click start button to stop button.

**My question is how to save the updated SCNNode over time from the moment when I click start button to stop button?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure what your goal is? Do you want to save the vertex positions over time or just the vertex positions for the last update?

Right now you are obtaining the geometry whenever it is updated, and then saving the vertex positions for that specific geometry. Next time the geometry updates the previous data would therefore be lost. Intstead of re-declaring the lastPosition variable every update you would have to append the new data to the array if you wish to keep previous data.

Again, I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do so this might not be helpful

Comment: Thank you so much for response! Sorry the naming was a little bit confused! What I am trying to to is to save the vertex positions over time. I have a start button to collect data and a stop button to stop recording. I would like to collect those projected vertices between the moment I click start until I hit stop. I am editing the post!

Comment: Does that make a bit clearer? Please let me know and thanks for your time!

Comment: I see. Then I think you would need to do what I just said. When performing the map operation on the vertex data you need to append the resulting array to the global CGPoint array instead of re-declaring it

Comment: Thanks for the repose! That does make sense why the previous data is not save! I am wondering would you have a minute to drop an example for "append the resulting array to the global CGPoint array"? I guess that's the main point that I am missing for the start button but I am sorry that I am not too familiar with append

Comment: Hi @A.Claesson! I tried your suggestion earlier! It does seem allowing me to append the data. However, when I comes with join(), for some reason, I still could not figure out why, that it again only provide me one set of the data instead of the whole. Would you have time to give me some insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63362173/swift-how-to-append-the-whole-data-set-instead-one-portion-using-joinseparator? BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to save the vertex positions each time they are updated, keeping track of all previous updates as well as the most recent one. In order to do this you simply need to append the new vertex position array to the global array with saved data.

```
 var savedPositions = [CGPoint]()
 var beginSaving = false

 func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        guard anchor == currentFaceAnchor,
            let contentNode = selectedContentController.contentNode,
            contentNode.parent == node
            else { return }
        for vertex in vertices {
            let projectedPoint = sceneView.projectPoint(node.convertPosition(SCNVector3(vertex), to: nil))
            if beginSaving {
               savedPositions.append(CGPoint(x: projectedPoint.x, y: projectedPoint.y))
            }
        }
        selectedContentController.session = sceneView?.session
        selectedContentController.sceneView = sceneView
        selectedContentController.renderer(renderer, didUpdate: contentNode, for: anchor)
}

@IBAction private func startPressed() {
    beginSaving = true
}

@IBAction private func stopPressed() {
    beginSaving = false
    ....//do whatever with your array of saved positions
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I am giving it a try and I will give you an update!

Answer (score 1):

SceneKit calls this method exactly once per frame.  If you do stuff inside the renderer, you gotta "get it done" and get out, otherwise it can have an impact on FPS.

If you need to move or check a lot of loop stuff, you can use timers to perform those efforts separately and that allows you some control over it.  You can still keep your FPS up and break loops up or chunk work in the timers.  If you do this, just make sure you put timers in the main thread.

You might also look at: node.presentation, ie: properties reflect the transitory values determined by any in-flight animations currently affecting the node.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Do you have an example on this? I am also wondering whether its applicable to use `func projectPoint(_ point: SCNVector3) -> SCNVector3` to get the updated nodes instead. But I couldn't find more info here..

Comment: Try this post:  47655786, it elaborates on projectPoint pretty well.  I use node.presentation at times, but I'd try it first and see if you really need it.