# How do I add a drag and drop gesture to SCNNode?

Tags: swift, swiftui, scenekit, draggable, gesture

My program creates two nodes:

```swift
let scene1 = SCNScene(named: "wheelbarrow.usdz")!
let scene2 = SCNScene(named: "tv_retro.usdz")!

let firstNode = scene1.rootNode.childNode(withName: "wheelbarrow", recursively: true)!
firstNode.position.x = -100
let secondNode = scene2.rootNode.childNode(withName: "tv_retro", recursively: true)!
secondNode.position.x = 100
        
sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(firstNode)
sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(secondNode)
```

How do I add a drag and drop gesture for each node?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "Drag and Drop" Gesture. I assume, you want to be able to "pick-up" an object  like with you finger touching the screen and when the Finger gets released the Object stays at it's new place. You can use i.Ex. a Pan Gesture Handler, that performs a hitTest on Touches Began, if the object is found you modify the position during Touches Changed Sequence and released on Touches ended event. Note, you will have to add some location point unprojection, because you are in 3D Space. Search for tutorials how to do this stuff. Good luck!

Comment: I know all this, but when I write the drag-and-drop code, the panning gesture is disabled. 
I would like to see an example code with a coordinator

Comment: Maybe this can help you, it's for ARKit. You can try to make a SceneKit only implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50131675/arkit-move-object-with-pangesture-the-right-way/56236958#56236958

Comment: It uses VirtualObject () instead of SCNNode. This example didn't give me any implementation ideas